# Using bash variables for range in sed

Tags: bash, sed

```
sed -n '5,10 p' < /proc/cpuinfo
```

prints 5-10 lines of the file /proc/cpuinfo

I want to use something like

```
start=5
end=10
sed -n '$start,$end p' < /proc/cpuinfo
```

so that I can change the values of start and end form a script.

Comment: Use double quote `"` instead of single one `'`

Answer (score 8):

You need to use double quotes for variable expansion:

```
start=5 end=10; sed -n "$start,$end p" < /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something other than `sed`, e.g. `awk`, you can try this:

```
start=5; 
end=10; 
awk 'NR>='$start' && NR<='$end' {print $0}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

`NR` is the row/line number in the file.